# Is the callback functionality of SocketIO a feature exclusive to SocketIO? And if so, how is the header formed?

Tags: android, ios, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm creating a native mobile project that will use SocketIO on NodeJS as the communications API.

We would like to use the callback functionality of SocketIO, but on native iOS (or Android).

However, the callback functionality doesn't appear in any client implementation of WebSockets that I've found so I am guessing it is a feature exclusive to SocketIO?

If so, what is the header information before the payload that socketIO uses to make this possible.

Over the wire I can see some binary before the JSON payload, but I'm not enough of a JS guru to analyse how the callback functionality on the client side is done, so that I can replicate that in ObjC and Java.

Comment: The binary before the payload are WebSocket headers, which are in no way specific to Socket.IO.  You can learn about them if you'd like by reading the relevant RFCs, but you'd be much better off using a library that already knows how to parse/build them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My edit of Maksims wasn't accepted yet so I just wanted to provide a concise answer for anyone else looking.

### SocketIO

Does have a header that packages each message, so it requires the use of a native SocketIO implementation, not just a WebSocket implementation.

https://github.com/pkyeck/socket.IO-objc

Is a library native to iOS that does implement SocketIO and it also implements the extremely handy callbacks feature available to SocketIO.

```
- (void) sendJSON:(NSDictionary *)data withAcknowledge:(SocketIOCallback)function;
```

I haven't found an implementation of the same for Android yet, and if it doesn't exist by December, will probaly create one myself.

Answer (score 1):

Socket.IO is not just WebSockets, but many protocols and work arounds that it will use and fallback to older ones with attempt to establish most reliable and real-time communication layer.
It is actually bunch of protocols. So if you are looking to communicate with Android or iOS, then consider one single protocol, that would be pure WebSockets like this one: https://github.com/einaros/ws

Then you need to have native WebSockets library for Android and iOS. Although do not expect they to behave the way you get use to in node.js as those platforms are totally different. There might be pull of messages instead of event-driven (callbacks).

WebSocket it self is message based protocol and sends data over TCP as full or partial messages with extra framing (header) for each message that contains some data about message, like type, length, masking etc. You don't need to get into low level understanding of WebSockets in order to use them.

Socket.IO sends JSON data in their messages and just does own job to make sure there is neat and usefull way to emit and catch events.

Please check few libraries like: https://github.com/pkyeck/socket.IO-objc for iOS (socket.io client), or https://github.com/koush/android-websockets

Those libraries actually handle their callbacks so you don't need to understand how WebSockets or Socket.IO works inside.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but do you have any idea what is in the SocketIO payloads other than just the json string? It builds some kind of header, and it's how it implements the callback function, I'm primarily interested in the callback functionality.

Comment: Callback functionality has nothing to do with actual data sent over the protocols, apart of name of event library will trigger after.
Callback functionality can't be done by just JSON object or any similar data sent over network.
But still, quickly looking into Dev Tools > Network > WebSockets in Chrome, message looks like that:
`5:::{"name":"lobby","args":[{"users":2,"match":4}]}`, where `lobby` is name of message and `args` has array of values that will be passed to callback.

Comment: Sure, Callback functionality being an exclusive feature to SocketIO was my assumption, and the header packing was my question. Still trying to figure out the schema of the header.

Comment: Open DevTools in chrome, go to Network tab and tick "WebSockets" below, then you'll see all strings of all messages. So you can simply parse it. Looks like you just need to loose initial part before first `{` and the rest will be pure JSON, so can parse it with favorite JSON parser.

Comment: Well I'm trying to retain and create those headers because my question is to recreate the callback functionality of SocketIO natively.

So I really need the schema.

Comment: Why wont you use ready solutions like: https://github.com/pkyeck/socket.IO-objc ?

Comment: Looking deeper at that again, it does use callbacks! Thanks!

Comment: Just waiting for the edit to take place and I'll mark the answer correct. Thanks for your help.